# couldn't find IP in eth0

Tags: ethernet

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04. I started the terminal and hit 'ifconfig' but couldn't find the IP in eth0. I tried a couple of things to remediate it like:

1. editing '/etc/network/interfaces'
2. editing '/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules' followed by 'reboot'

Please help resolving the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by DevRobot you can look at the output of `ifconfig` or `ip addr` to find the current ip address of `eth0`.

This will work only if `eth0` exists and only if it has currently got an ip address.

if `eth0` exists but you can not see an IP address then first check that your ethernet is connected, the output of `ip addr` should show `state UP`.

Then presuming that your network has a standard home router, you expect to get your ip address over DHCP, which is most likely, then you can try the following command:

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

Then check your ip with the command `ip addr` again.

If the `dhclient` command worked, then this indicates a probable issue with your configuration, I recommend posting your `/etc/network/interfaces` file so we can check it.

Comment: Thanks Paul.

file '/etc/network/interfaces' show as follows:
**********************
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
***********************

Comment: @ghost0806 Welcome to ask Ubuntu! If this answer helped you please click the check mark on the left to thank the user and allow others to easily find the information.

Comment: @ghost0806 Thanks, it doesn't look like there is a section for `eth0`, did using `dhclient` work for you? Could you please add the file contents to your original question so that it can be formated correctly? Could you please give the output of `ip addr`

Comment: dhclient didn't work for me..

Comment: Output for  'ip addr'
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:19:f2:80:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: 3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:fb:90:f0:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.9/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::222:fbff:fe90:f0b8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: According to this output, your eth0 interface is disconnected (is the cable plugged in?), however your wifi *is* connected on wlan0.

Are you using a wired network connection?  Your current IP on your wifi connection is 192.168.1.9

Comment: Yes I am using wifi connection...however I need to connect this machine to another using ssh...what should I do..?

Comment: well eth0 is usually for wired ethernet ports. wlan0 is your wifi connection.

I guess you've been looking at a guide and it's told you use to use eth0.

If your using wifi, just use wlan0 whereever the guide says use eth0

Comment: If you are trying to ssh into your machine, use the ip address for wlan0.

Comment: thanks much Paul...I will try with wlan0 but I have another ques for you now...I have installed eclipse indigo but wouldn't start...installed it in opt/ folder...but when I hit eclipse...it didn't do anything...really appreciate your help...